# Question for a newbie: Bootstrap 5 | Positioning text and logo problem

Tags: html, css

I recently started with Bootstrap 5 with big enthusiasm and started watching tutorials.

[In this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJF4ldO91n4&t=1104s) he is adding text in the right corner and places the logo in the left corner. I wrote the same code, but in my *index.html* file [I did not get the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgbDi.png). What am I missing?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!---------------------------------- TOPBAR ---------------------------------->
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-8 pull-right">
      <p><a href="+188888888">Call Us For Maintence Quickly!</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<!---------------------------------- NAVBAR ---------------------------------->
<nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container"></div>
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x145/000/fff" alt="LogoTitle"></a>
</nav>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be getting Bootstrap v4 and v5 classes mixed up as well as your element nesting. For the top bar, you'd want something like:

```
<div class="col-8 align-self-end text-end">
```

if you plan to add additional columns to that container later. But the better option is likely:

```
<div class="row-cols text-end">
```

For the navbar, your error is that the <a><img></a> elements are outside and after the .container <div>. You'd want either:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a><img></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

or:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a><img></a>
  <div class="container"></div>
</nav>
```

...depending on what you're after. Neither of these are really the best way to structure a navbar or container, though. I'd highly recommend reading [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/) for version 5, as it's likely a much better resource. Note that your tutorial is for version 4, which is distinctly different.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `a` element inside the container. For example:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x145/000/fff" alt="LogoTitle">
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```